# Can I put a php link to $query?

Tags: php, html, mysql

So here's my code

```
mysql_select_db($database_Myconnec, $Myconnec);    
$query_service = "SELECT service.Service_id,            
IF(physical.Service_id IS NULL, ('Add'), ('Edit')) as physical  
FROM service LEFT JOIN physical ON (service.Service_id = physical.Service_id )";  
$service = mysql_query($query_service, $Myconnec) or die(mysql_error());  
$row_service = mysql_fetch_assoc($service);  
$totalRows_service = mysql_num_rows($service);



    <table border="1" class="floatedTable">
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">Service ID</td>
    <td><div align="center">Physical Check</td>
  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center"><?php echo $row_service['Service_id']; ?></td>
      <td><div align="center"><?php echo $row_service['physical']; ?></td>  
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_service = mysql_fetch_assoc($service)); ?>
</table>
```

What I want is the word 'Add' and 'Edit' to appear as a clickable php links when it is shown in the tables how do i do that?

Comment: Just add another column and put the button or anchor tag there.

Comment: please give an example as to what your desired output looks like

Comment: To begin with you should use MySQLi. Because in PHP7 you can not use the MySQL. Change your code to use mysqli

Comment: Do not use Mysql. it is deprecated in php7

Comment: @C.Geek so i have two columns one for the id and another for the physical check so if the id hasn't done the check yet the physical will appear the text as 'Add' with a link to go to the add page after adding it will redirect back to this page and instead the text 'Add' will change to 'Edit' because it has been added and will take to the edit page instead

Comment: @VirajShah how? sorry i'm very new to this my friends bailed me with this project so i'm doing this alone with no clue just the internet to help

Comment: See @RamRaider answer. Normally you don't build language specific code within a query. It gets very messy with all the quotes and escaping characters. Best to do this sort of thing within the server-side language.

Comment: is it possible to use javascript to check what the text is and put a linkk to it?

Comment: @JoshuaJohn instead of 'Add', '<a href="http://link.to.go.here/add.php?id=1234">Add</a>'

Is that more like it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, if I understood, do something akin to this perhaps

```
<table border="1" class="floatedTable">
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">Service ID</td>
    <td><div align="center">Physical Check</td>
  </tr>
  <?php 

  do {

    $id=$row_service['Service_id'];
    $phys=$row_service['physical'];
    $action=$phys=='Add' ? 'add.php' : 'edit.php'; #assumed script names correspond to text

  ?>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center"><?php echo $id; ?></td>
      <td><div align="center"><?php echo "<a href='{$action}?id={$id}' title='$phys'>$phys</a>";?></td>  
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_service = mysql_fetch_assoc($service)); ?>
</table>
```

---

```
# view.php
# --------

<table border="1" class="floatedTable">
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">Service ID</td>
    <td><div align="center">Physical Check</td>
  </tr>
  <?php 

  do {

    $id=$row_service['Service_id'];
    $phys=$row_service['physical'];
    $action=$phys=='Add' ? 'add.php' : 'edit.php'; #assumed script names correspond to text

  ?>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center"><?php echo $id; ?></td>
      <td><div align="center"><?php echo "<a href='{$action}?id={$id}' title='$phys'>$phys</a>";?></td>  
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_service = mysql_fetch_assoc($service)); ?>
</table>



# add.php
# -------

$id = isset( $_GET['id'] ) ? $_GET['id'] : false;
if( $id ){

    /* 
        generate form to add record
        use $id somewhere?
    */

}




# edit.php
# --------
$id = isset( $_GET['id'] ) ? $_GET['id'] : false;
if( $id ){

    /* 
        do stuff - generate form to edit content etc 
        use $id to lookup data
    */

}
```

---

With reference to your last comments regarding removal of hyperlink for specific values - perhaps try like this?

```
  do {

    $id=$row_service['Service_id'];
    $phys=$row_service['physical'];
    $action=$phys=='Add' ? 'add.php' : 'edit.php'; #assumed script names correspond to text

    if( strtolower( $phys )=='wait' )$content=$phys;
    else $content="<a href='{$action}?id={$id}' title='$phys'>$phys</a>";
  ?>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center"><?php echo $id; ?></td>
      <td><div align="center"><?php echo $content; ?></td>  
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_service = mysql_fetch_assoc($service)); ?>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks this works but there's one slight problem i need to take the service id  with it to so when i click add it'll will take the id with it to be input as the physical.Service_id

Comment: that is hopefully what `?id={$id}` does in the above

Comment: it's completely blank

Comment: here is the code on the the add page of the id textbox section <input type="text" name="Service_id" value="<?php echo $row_showservice['Service_id']; ?>" size="32" />

Comment: do you mean `?id=` is what you see rather than say `?id=23` etc

Comment: oic - on the `add` page you do not necessarily have the recordset available I guess and you are passing the id with a querystring parameter from the code above - ie: `<a href='add.php?id=23'>add</a>` so you would use `$_GET['id']` on the `add` page

Comment: Passing the id of an existing record to the `add` page makes no sense if you are to add a new record as the new record will not use the same id. Passing the id to the edit page however is totally different as you need the id to lookup the particular record for editing

Comment: the service table and the physical table are one to one key relations so each services only needs one physical check each time

Comment: i've seen your edit and tried but it doesn't seem to work? i think i've putted in a wrong section or something

Comment: can you update your question with the code ( maybe not all of it ) from `add.php` and/or `edit.php` so we might see what you are meaning?

Comment: nvm i've figured where to put $_GET['id'] that you mentioned my mistake thank you so much for your help now i can rest easy

Comment: Another question if I may? The text add and edit what if I want it to appear as a simple text and another to appear as a link is it possible?

Comment: how do you mean? I would say that it is possible but not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: For example 'wait' & 'add' I don't want 'wait' to appear as a link

Comment: Even if I removed the PHP link the text still has this underline link and still clickable

Comment: You're a life saver man works like a charm! Shame that i can't post a question about things i'm stuck or needed help again but have to wait like 4 days